# Slice copy error while using two data frame and updating one of the column into other datafarame pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to compare  2 df and fill the values of one data frame into another by creating a  column

have used the following code

```
df['location']=df1['location']
for i in  range(0,len(df)):
    for j in  range(0,len(df1)):

        if df['Name'][i]==df1['Name'][j]:
            df['location'][i] =(df1['location'][j])
```

df are listed below [image]

[image]

I am getting the following error.

```
<ipython-input-14-7b3141ebb9f0>:7: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['location'][i] =(df1['location'][j])
```

i am able to get the desired output irrespective of the error warning..!

result :[image]

If i use the following command  i can bypass this error/warning

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Need to know is there a way to avoid warning without using the above-said command. Need your help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C'], 'location':['South','north','east']})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','A','B','C'], 'count':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df
```

dict for reference

```
d=dict(zip(df.Name,df.location))
```

Map to Transfer

```
df1['location']=df1.Name.map(f)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: IF IT WORKED,please press the up arrow tonupvote so that people can confidently use the answer if having similar issues